# Is there a syntax for incomplete nested type without a forward declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11, nested, forward-declaration

The following program produces a diagnostic error.

```
#include <memory>
class Containing {
    // class Nested;                 // [1]: This line seems required.
    typedef std::shared_ptr<class Nested> Ptr;
    class Nested {
        Ptr & ptr ();
        void foo (const Ptr &p) {
            p->ptr() = ptr()->ptr(); // [2]: Error here without [1]
        }
    };
};
int main () {}
```

The produced diagnostic is:

> ```
> prog.cpp:8:14: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Nested'
>              p->ptr() = ptr()->ptr();
>               ^
> prog.cpp:4:35: error: forward declaration of 'class Nested'`
>      typedef std::shared_ptr<class Nested> Ptr;
>                                    ^
> ```

However, if I uncomment the forward declaration, the compilation succeeds. I believe the reason is that `Nested` is assumed to be not nested when it is used for `shared_ptr<>`. If that is so, is there a syntax I can use to let `shared_ptr<>` know that `Nested` is nested without the forward declaration? Something like:

```
class Containing {
    typedef std::shared_ptr<class Containing::Nested> Ptr;
    //...
```

---

This question uses a minimal example to illustrate the problem. The actual structure looks like:

```
class Containing {
    typedef std::shared_ptr<class NestedInterface> Ptr;
    class NestedObject {
        Ptr ptr_;
        //...
    };
    class NestedInterface {
        virtual NestedObject & object () = 0;
        void foo (const Ptr &p) {
            // ...
        }
        //...
    };
    class NestedType1 : NestedInterface {
        NestedObject obj_;
        NestedObject & object () { return obj_; }
        //...
    };
    class NestedType2 : NestedInterface {
        Containing &c_;
        NestedObject & object () { return c_.nested_object_; }
        //...
    };
    //...
```

Comment: One alternative would be to move the typedef line to after the end of the "class Nested {}" block... of course, you wouldn't be able to use the typedef within that block anymore, so you'd need to explicitly specify the underlying type ("std::shared_ptr<class Nested>") in your method arguments, instead.

Comment: I believe you could also place the typedef *in* the `Nested` definition, if you were only planning to use `Ptr` in the scope of `Nested`. It certainly [compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74c78deb314e8d87).

Comment: Producing the example that motivates the question would not make the example minimal anymore. Do all questions have to be fully motivated?

Comment: Then why not make the `Ptr` typedef of `Nested` public, if you typedef it in the `Nested` class? I'm assuming there's a reason you want to use `Ptr` rather than something that indicates what `Ptr` points *to?*

Comment: Don't waste time writing a page of code motivating the question... not everyone on StackOverflow is incapable of answering unmotivated questions.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I thought so. Requiring the full example for the question basically demotivates the asker from doing the work to produce the minimal example.

Comment: @101010: Comments such as *Why not do it that way instead* are basically asking for the reason for the question.

Comment: @101010: I do have a nice sense of humor, but the original comment did not seem to be an attempt at humor. (The Hamlet comment, while humorous, did seem to be asking for a motivation regardless of that.) Either way, the problem is that I myself find it extremely irritating when people force the OP to motivate their question (I've been in the same position as the OP and it drives me nuts to have to waste time doing that unnecessarily).

Comment: @jhx. Sorry. I didn't mean it that way, more as offering a possible way of accomplishing the same task, if that makes any sense at all.

Comment: Except when the *class-key identifier;* syntax is used, a class first declared in an *elaborated-type-specifier* is always [introduced in a namespace or block scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423481/a-class-name-introduced-inside-a-class-is-not-treated-as-a-nested-class-name), and never a class scope.

Comment: @T.C.: Thanks T.C. My question looks sort of like a duplicate of that one. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't.

However, you shouldn't need to avoid the forward declarations at all. This works:

```
class Containing {
    class NestedInterface;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<NestedInterface> Ptr;
    class NestedObject {
        Ptr ptr_;
        //...
    };
    class NestedInterface {
        // ...
    };
};
```

Sometimes cross-dependencies inside the classes might make this hard to do. In that case, all you need to do is to avoid defining the referencing classes inline, and to instead declare the *other* classes out-of-line, like this:

```
class Containing {
    class NestedInterface;
    class NestedObject;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<NestedInterface> Ptr;
};
class Containing::NestedObject {
    Ptr ptr_;
    //...
};
class Containing::NestedInterface {
};
```

Note that, in general, in C++, nested classes are not to be used on a whim the way you might in other languages -- you can generally achieve the same effect with outer classes, and they behave much better that way. (They don't require the definition of the outer class.) Only in a few cases have they been absolutely necessary. (`std::allocator<T>::rebind<U>` comes to mind.)

Comment: That still has a forward declaration, though.  (line 2)

Comment: @donjuedo: Hence the **"*No*"** and the **"*work around*"**, if you actually read the first line.

Comment: Yes, I did actually read the first line.  What I'm missing is the motive to reorganize the rest of the declaration, since it doesn't change the "no work around" part.  You said he needs to, but you didn't say why.

Comment: @donjuedo: Well that's a very different question. Yeah, you're right, it wasn't necessary here; I'll change the answer to fix that. Sometimes the members have cross-references that make this approach useful, though, so I illustrated it.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep that declaration `class Nested;` in there.

Declaring the `Ptr` and `Nested` relationship is a chicken-and-egg problem, and  the forward declaration is the proper way to handle that.

The compiler needs to know that the token `Nested` is a class, and not something else.  At the point when the compiler reaches `Ptr`, that info is enough, and details of the class are not yet relevant.  Then the compiler reaches the complete `Nested` declaration, and the details can be used for all future uses of the class.

Comment: The `class Nested` forward declaration makes it clear to the compiler that `Nested` is nested. Note the use of `class Nested` inside `shared_ptr<>`.

Comment: I gather you mean the keyword `class` in the template type area should be enough, so that earlier forward declaration would be redundant.  Logical.