# Alternative to forward declaration

Tags: c++

I noticed that **prepending the `class` or `struct` keyword to a type that would otherwise need be forward declared** works as if that type was forward declared:

```
// struct Test; forward declaration commented

void* foo(struct Test* t) // C style function parameter - This works !
{
    return t; 
}
```

I wasn't aware of that. I wonder if it's standard C++ or an extension and whether the `struct` keyword before the parameter works as a forward declaration or another mechanism kicks in.

Furthermore, after such a usage the "next" function can use the type without prepending any keywords :

```
void* oof(Test* t);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b413aa43472ff59d)

Comment: Yes, an *elaborated-type-specifier* can be used to declare a type, even outside a "normal" forward declaration. [The semantics is somewhat different, though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423481/a-class-name-introduced-inside-a-class-is-not-treated-as-a-nested-class-name/24424033#24424033).

Comment: sorry I misread your question then.

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou just that did

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is legal, but probably not a good idea.

From **[basic.scope.pdecl]**/6:

> [...] — for an *elaborated-type-specifier* of the form
>   *class-key* *identifier*
>   if the *elaborated-type-specifier* is used in the *decl-specifier-seq* or *parameter-declaration-clause* of a
>   function defined in namespace scope, **the *identifier* is declared as a *class-name* in the namespace that
>   contains the declaration** [...]

For example:

```
namespace mine {
    struct T* foo(struct S *);
//  ^^^^^^^^^---------------- decl-specifier-seq
//                ^^^^^^^^^^--- parameter-declaration-clause
}
```

This introduces `T` and `S` as class-names and `foo` as a function name into `namespace mine`.

---

Note that the behavior is different in C; the struct name is only valid within the scope of the function.

> #### 6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers
>
> 4 - [...] If the declarator or type specifier that
>   declares the identifier appears [...] within the list of parameter declarations in
>   a function definition, the identifier has *block scope*, which terminates at the end of the
>   associated block. If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears
>   within the list of parameter declarations in a function prototype (not part of a function
>   definition), the identifier has *function prototype scope*, which terminates at the end of the
>   function declarator.

gcc gives an appropriate warning for this usage in C code:

```
a.c:3:18: warning: ‘struct Test’ declared inside parameter list
 void* foo(struct Test* t)
                  ^
a.c:3:18: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
```