# Elaborated Type specifiers for class type

Tags: c++

This is regarding the question

[A class name introduced inside a class is not treated as a nested class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423481/a-class-name-introduced-inside-a-class-is-not-treated-as-a-nested-class-name?answertab=active).

I am confused why Part1 and Part2 are different with respect to §3.3.2 [basic.scope.pdecl]/p7 of the standard:

Both are Elaborated Type specifiers and should fall into same section But it seems that there scope seems to be different

#### Part 1:

```
struct A 
{
    struct B;
    B* m_b;
};
```

#### Part 2:

```
struct A 
{
    struct B* m_b;
};
```

Please guide me in this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A class name introduced inside a class is not treated as a nested class name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423481/a-class-name-introduced-inside-a-class-is-not-treated-as-a-nested-class-name)

Comment: I need a clarification of answer accepted in the linked question

Comment: Tjese declarations nehave differently because the standard says they should behave differently, and the accepted answer quotes the passage that says it.

Comment: but both of the declaration are of type " class-key identifier" and fit into "otherwise" section resulting a declaration at innermost namespace containing them.. can you please explain a little more ?

Comment: You are misreading the quote. Read it again, very carefully. Do you see the semicolon? Can you ignore it?

Comment: Thanks n.m..perfect clarification ..it would be really helpful if you can clarify one more doubt here ...in 3.3.2 first section ( with semicolon) contains form class-key attr-specifier identifier.whereas in otherwise section attr-specifier is missing..is that difference plays any role?

Comment: Yes, attribute-specifiers are a part of a declaration, while the other section doesn't describe a declaration. When you say `struct Foo * foo;`, `struct Foo` is not a declaration, though the entire line is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this little example will help to elaborate:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B {

    void call() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
};

struct A {

    struct B* p;
};

struct A2 {

    struct B;
    struct B* p;
};

struct A2::B {
    void call() { std::cout << "A2::B" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    B pb;
    A2::B pb2;

    auto a = A { &pb };

    a.p->call();

    auto a2 = A2 { &pb2 };
    a2.p->call();

    return 0;
}
```

expected results:

```
B
A2::B
```

Summary:

A::p is a B*

A2::p is a A2::B*

A2::B and B are entirely different classes

Comment: Thanks Richard for your answer,,It really adds lot to my knowledge but it still does not answer my question. struct B in struct A2 should reslove to globally defined struct B as what struct B* p; does. In short where in the standard mentioned the difference between struct B * Pb and struct B; B * Pb in terms of scope/point of declaration of struct/class B?