# What is different about C++ class function parameter syntax when one of them is a struct?

Tags: c++, struct

When writing a new class function, it is usually safe for me to copy the function definition's first line (from a source file) to the class header to add the declaration so that it is part of the class. I don't usually use structs in C++ but now that I have, I ran into the case where there seems to be some special case about specifying the struct in the parameter list in the definition. The struct is a data member of the same class.

Function definition in header file:

```
int freq_sort(unsigned char* source, struct freq_pair* target);
```

First line of that function definition in the source file:

```
int TargaImage::freq_sort(unsigned char* source, struct freq_pair* target){
```

Compiler error regarding declaration:

```
TargaImage.cpp:324:5: error: no declaration matches ‘int TargaImage::freq_sort(unsigned char*, TargaImage::freq_pair*)’
  324 | int TargaImage::freq_sort(unsigned char* source, struct freq_pair* target){
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Compiler error suggesting the correct definition:

```
TargaImage.h:96:13: note: candidate is: ‘int TargaImage::freq_sort(unsigned char*, freq_pair*)’
   96 |         int freq_sort(unsigned char* source, struct freq_pair* target);
      |             ^~~~~~~~~
```

Struct data member:

```
        struct freq_pair {
            unsigned char val;
            int count;
        };
```

I see the key difference in what the compiler sees is the scope resolution operator used with the struct parameter in the definition but not the declaration. I do not understand why this is. What is happening here?

I tried to add class scope to the struct parameter in either the definition, the declaration, or both in order to cajole it into working but to no avail. Even if it did though, I wouldn't understand what the issue is.

What's my next step to finding the issue here?

Thanks,
Trent

**EDIT 1:**

Here is the minimum reproducible code of the original problem with no changes from insights gained from the comments.

```
class TargaImage
{
  public:
    //function
    int freq_sort(unsigned char* source, struct freq_pair* target);

    //data member 
    struct freq_pair {
       unsigned char val;
       int count;
    };
};

int TargaImage::freq_sort(unsigned char* source, struct freq_pair* target){
  return 0;  
}

int main(){
  TargaImage obj;
  return 0;
}
```

Now I understand to think of structs in a similar way as classes.  So, if I'm essentially defining a new "class"(struct) inside my original class, the rules for including that class for use must be different than the usual preprocessor directive. I'd think that since the new freq_pair "class"(struct) is inside the original TargaImage class that its definition is within the scope of a TargaImage member function. So, remove struct keyword from parameters. But I get the error:

```
main.cpp:6:42: error: ‘freq_pair’ has not been declared
    6 |     int freq_sort(unsigned char* source, freq_pair* target);
      |
```

So my conclusion is that freq_pair is out of scope of TargaImage although it is defined inside the class. Is this conclusion correct? How should I inform TargaImage::freq_sort(...) of the class type freq_pair?

I thought adding a C style struct as a data member was a good idea, but a main takeaway may be to define a class elsewhere that holds the pair of data members that the struct was holding.

Comment: The function doesn't seem to be part of the struct/class, at least not from what you have shown. Although you are missing quite a bit for a [mcve]

Comment: Structs aren't a thing in C++.  The `struct` keyword is just an alternate way to declare a class (and a C++ class happens to be similar to a C struct in many ways).  It's also grammatical to stick the keyword `struct` in front of a class name, but that doesn't do anything: it's just there to maintain compatibility with C.

Comment: Why do you include the word `struct` in `int freq_sort(unsigned char* source, struct freq_pair* target);`? You don't put `class` in similar places, do you?

Comment: No functions are part of the struct- only the unsigned char & int as shown in the last code snippet. But I may not be fully understanding your comment. @UnholySheep

Comment: Perhaps its in C only and not C++, but I find the keyword struct to essentially be part of the type definition. I could not for instance, instantiate a new struct local variable without it. That is why I thought (incorrectly here) to add it in the parameter list. @TedLyngmo

Comment: "_I could not for instance, instantiate a new struct local variable without it_" - Try it, you will get surprised :-) `freq_pair my_local_instance;`

Comment: @TrentWilson That is true in C, but not the case in C++. Make sure you are indeed always compiling as C++ and if you get an error while compiling as C++ this means that you didn't actually declare the `struct` before you used it. If you then add `struct` as a keyword in the variable definition, you are declaring a new `struct` in the scope of the variable definition, which may be a *different class* than the `struct` defined later in a different scope that you intended to refer to.

Comment: @hegel5000 There *are* small differences between `struct` and `class` in C++. In a `struct`, members are `public` by default, in a `class` they are `private` by default. The *default* inheritance relationship for a `struct` is *public inheritance*, for a `class` it is *private inheritance*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl  I had completely forgotten about the inheritance thing! (I've always defensively stuck the `public` keyword on when inheriting)

Comment: @hegel5000 For this question it is probably also important to realize that `struct` in a variable declaration *does do something*: If name lookup does not find a declaration for the type, `struct` will (instead of failing) declare a new class in the scope of the variable declaration. That is probably what is happening here one way or another, but there is no way to say for sure until OP provides more code.

Comment: Is the definition of freq_pair in this header file (if so is the definition before the definition of TargaImage)? In another header file (if so have you included that file)? Since you only need a pointer you could also put the line `struct freq_pair;` before the definition of TargaImage (but you will need the full definition before you can implement it)

Answer (score 3):

C++ is compiled from the top down to the bottom of the source code. Except in templates, each time an identifier is encountered, *name lookup* is performed. This means the compiler tries to find a reachable declaration of the identifier in the previous part of the source code.

Here you use the identifier `freq_pair` the first time in the function parameter inside

```
int freq_sort(unsigned char* source, struct freq_pair* target);
```

Because it was not declared beforehand, the compiler does not know yet what `freq_pair` is supposed to be. Usually that would result in an error saying that `freq_pair` is undeclared. However the `struct` keyword basically tells the compiler: "*`freq_pair` is a class type and if you don't find such a class type, then declare it here.*"

Therefore `freq_pair` will be declared, but the question is *where exactly* (i.e. in which *scope*) it will be declared. It could be declared as a nested class (`struct` and `class` both introduce classes, in C++ there is no distinction between the two with regards to type identity) inside `TargaImage`, as a local class to the function or as a global class. In fact the latter is the case, as [[basic.scope.pdecl]/7.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope#pdecl-7.2) of the C++17 standard (draft N4659) specifies (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423481/a-class-name-introduced-inside-a-class-is-not-treated-as-a-nested-class-name) for a similar case):

> for an *elaborated-type-specifier* of the form
>
> > *class-key identifier*
>
> if [...]; otherwise, except as a friend declaration, the identifier is declared in the smallest namespace or block scope that contains the declaration.

An *elaborated-type-specifier* is a type specifier that uses `struct` or one of the other *class-key* keywords, i.e. exactly what you have with `struct freq_pair`. Your function declaration is inside a class scope (which is neither a namespace scope nor a block scope), therefore the declaration of `freq_pair` cannot be placed there. The next smallest scope containing `class TargaImage {...};` is the global scope, which *is* considered a namespace scope. Thus the line

```
int freq_sort(unsigned char* source, struct freq_pair* target);
```

declares a global `struct freq_pair` and the type referred to in the declaration is that type.

Then

```
struct freq_pair {
   unsigned char val;
   int count;
};
```

defines a class `freq_pair` nested inside the class `TargaImage`. This is *not the same* class as the global one your declared beforehand.

Then we come to the definition

```
int TargaImage::freq_sort(unsigned char* source, struct freq_pair* target){
    return 0;  
}
```

Here, because we are defining a function which is part of `TargaImage`, the name `freq_pair` is first looked up inside `TargaImage`, where we *now* see the definition `struct freq_pair {...};` which declared a `freq_pair` nested inside `TargaImage`, i.e. `TargaImage::freq_pair`. The `struct` keyword does not have any further effect if a type matching the name *can* be found, so `freq_pair` in this definition now refers to `TargaImage::freq_pair`.

As a result you have declared a member function taking a pointer to the global `::freq_pair`, but tried to define a member function taking a pointer to the nested `::TargaImage::freq_pair`. The compiler complains that these do not match up.

---

To resolve the issue remove all the `struct` keywords inside variable declarations and use it only to define or explicitly forward-declare classes. As you can see, using it as elaborated type specifier only causes headaches. The same rule applies to the other elaborated type specifiers, i.e. those beginning with `class`/`enum`/`union`.

Doing so will however result in an error because `freq_pair` is not found in the member declaration as I explained above. This is easily resolved by moving the definition of `freq_pair` before the point of use:

```
class TargaImage
{
public:
    //data member 
    struct freq_pair {
       unsigned char val;
       int count;
    };

    //function
    int freq_sort(unsigned char* source, freq_pair* target);
};

int TargaImage::freq_sort(unsigned char* source, freq_pair* target){
  return 0;  
}
```

If that is not possible for whatever reason, then you can use a forward declaration to make sure that the first lookup finds the correct type (even if it is *incomplete* at that point):

```
class TargaImage
{
  public:

    //explicit forward declaration
    struct freq_pair;

    //function
    int freq_sort(unsigned char* source, freq_pair* target);

    //data member 
    struct freq_pair {
       unsigned char val;
       int count;
    };
};

int TargaImage::freq_sort(unsigned char* source, freq_pair* target){
  return 0;  
}
```

---

Also note that `freq_pair` is a *nested class*, not a *data member*.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword struct is optional, and normally not used, in C++ except when defining or (forward) declaring the type.

If you remove "struct" from the parameter list in the function declaration, you will get a different error indicating that the type freq_pair has not been declared.

If you move the definition of freq_pair before the function definition in the class it will compile as expected. Alternatively, a forward declaration of the type in the class before the function will also work.

This is normal.

What I found surprising here is the error message you received. It indicated that due to your use of the keyword struct in the function declaration parameter list, the compiler has registered that parameter specifier as a forward declaration of a globally scoped struct freq_pair which is never defined in your code and is different from your nested type.

This form of forward declaration is a part of the standard as described and documented with references in uneven_mark's answer. In short, using the class or struct keyword makes this an "elaborated type specifier" and triggers this behavior. Further, also as pointed out in that answer, class scope is not considered by the standard to be an eligible scoping for the forward declared type, so in your case you end up with the type declared at global scope.

Comment: The unintuitive forward declaration into the global scope is indeed specified by the standard, see my answer or e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423481/a-class-name-introduced-inside-a-class-is-not-treated-as-a-nested-class-name).

Comment: @uneven_mark Thank you. I found part of this, but was missing a few pieces in trying to sort out the standard. +1 to your answer.