# struct fwd-declared in member-function parameter list not nested in enclosing struct

Tags: c++

I was trying to forward-declare nested type `struct A::impl` and run into this
issue.

The following code snippet compiles fine:

```
struct A {
    struct impl; // `struct impl` fwd declaration
    void f(impl); // A::f declaration
};

struct A::impl {}; // definition
void A::f(impl) {}
```

However, if I move the forward-declaration into the parameter list of member-function `A::f`, I get a compiler error:

```
struct A {
    void f(struct impl); // A::f declaration and `struct impl` fwd declaration
};

struct A::impl {}; // compile-time error
//struct impl {}; // < This compiles, instead
void A::f(impl) {}
```

It looks like I'm forward-declaring `struct impl` instead of `struct A::impl`.

The compiler error is (on Clang 14.0.0):

```
error: no struct named 'impl' in 'A'
struct A::impl {};
```

**Question:** why is

```
struct A {
    void f(struct impl);
};
```

different from

```
struct A {
    struct impl;
    void f(impl);
};
```

with respect to the scope of `struct impl`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is different about C++ class function parameter syntax when one of them is a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631258/what-is-different-about-c-class-function-parameter-syntax-when-one-of-them-is). The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58633772/12002570) in the linked dupe, explains using reference from the standard the behavior of the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference in what the forward declaration means here.

C++ Standard [[basic.scope.pdecl]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.scope.pdecl#7) reads:

> The point of declaration of a class first declared in an *elaborated-type-specifier* is as follows:
>
> - for a declaration of the form
>
> *class-key attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> identifier*`;`
>
> the *identifier* is declared to be a *class-name* in the scope that contains the declaration, otherwise
>
> - for an *elaborated-type-specifier* of the form
>
> *class-key identifier*
>
> if the *elaborated-type-specifier* is used in the *decl-specifier-seq* or *parameter-declaration-clause* of a function defined in namespace scope, the *identifier* is declared as a *class-name* in the namespace that contains the declaration; otherwise, except as a friend declaration, the *identifier* is declared in the smallest namespace or block scope that contains the declaration.

The original `struct impl;` within the definition of `class A` matches the first case, so it does forward declare `impl` in the immediate class scope, so as a member type.

In `void f(struct impl);` the `struct impl` is not a declaration all on its own with a semicolon, so the first case doesn't match. It's within a *parameter-declaration-clause*, but the function declaration is neither a definition nor at namespace scope. So we're left with the third case: the smallest enclosing namespace or block scope. It's not in any block scope at all, and the only namespace here is the global namespace, so it forward declares `struct ::impl`.

Because these details are tricky, I recommend always putting the forward declaration all on its own in the `class`/`struct`/`union` *name* `;` form, not inside any other syntax.

Answer (score 1):

> why is `struct A { void f(struct impl);};` different from `struct A { struct impl; void f(impl); };`?

The problem is that writing:

```
void f(struct impl); //does not forward declares impl
```

**does not declares** struct `impl` as a member struct of class `A`. Instead it just says that `f` is a member function that has a parameter of ***class-type*** `impl`. Moreover, there is also one more effect of having `struct impl` as a parameter of the member function `f`, which is that `struct impl` is **implicitly declared in the global namespace and not in the class scope** in your example. Thus, `A` has no nested class member named `impl` and hence you cannot provide an implementation for `A::impl` outside the class `A`.

```
//--------vvvv------>error because there is no member class named impl in struct A 
struct A::impl {};
```

---

To solve this, you must forward declare `impl` as you were originally doing.

```
struct A {
    struct impl; // nested struct member named impl
    void f(impl); // now impl can be used as a parameter because compiler know that impl is a nested struct
};

struct A::impl {}; // definition
void A::f(impl) {}
```

Comment: Apparently `void f(struct impl)` does forward-declare `impl`, but it does so at namespace scope: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1v7W97sYY

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Note that i removed that sentence some time ago from my answer. The problem is that it does not declares `impl` as a member struct and hence we cannot provide a definition outside `A` for `impl`  since it(`A`) has no member named `impl`.